# Comparar dos arreglos de objetos y obtener arreglo con los objetos diferentes. Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos arreglos como estos:

```js
  BaseDatos = [
    { bloque: 'Articulos', atributo: 'Keywords' },
    { bloque: 'Capacitacion', atributo: 'fecha_aceptacion' },
    { bloque: 'Libros', atributo: 'pais' },
    { bloque: 'Proyectos', atributo: 'paginas' },
    { bloque: 'Libros', atributo: 'volume' },
  ];

  esquemaJson = [
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Libros', atributoEntrante: 'paginas' },
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Articulos', atributoEntrante: 'Keywords' },
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Grado Academico', atributoEntrante: 'fecha_aceptacion'},
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Libros', atributoEntrante: 'volume' },
  ];
```

Y tengo una función en mi `.ts` de la siguiente forma:

```js
  funcion() {
    const similitud: any = [];
    this.BaseDatos.filter((d) => {
      this.esquemaJson.filter((s) => {
        if (
          d.bloque === s.bloqueEntrante &&
          d.atributo === s.atributoEntrante
        ) {
          similitud.push(d);
        }
      });
    });

    const nosimilitud = this.BaseDatos.filter((d) => !similitud.includes(d));
    console.log('similitud', similitud);
    console.log('no similitud', nosimilitud);

    // nosimilitud.forEach((element) => {
    //   console.log('elementoaborrar', element);
    // });
  }
```

Lo cual me devuelve en similitud:

```
similitud = [
  {
     atributo: "Keywords"
     bloque: "Articulos"
  },
  {
     atributo: "volume"
     bloque: "Libros"
   }
]
```

Y en no similitud:

```
nosimilitud = [
  {
     atributo: "fecha_aceptacion"
     bloque: "Capacitacion"
  },
  {
     atributo: "pais"
     bloque: "Libros"
   },
   {
     atributo: "paginas"
     bloque: "Proyectos"
   }
]
```

En el arreglo de `nosimilitud`  me devuelve los que no se encuentran en el arreglo de `esquemaJson` con respecto a `BaseDatos`. Cómo puedo hacer para que me devuelva los elementos que `esquemaJson`tiene y que `BaseDatos` no, en este caso sería:

```
 nosimilitud = [
    { 
       bloque: 'Libros', 
       atributo: 'paginas' 
    },
    {  bloque: 'Grado Academico', 
       atributo: 'fecha_aceptacion' 
    }
  ];
```

Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Código en stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-kxjmhh?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar la función **[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** de `JavaScript` de esta manera

```js
const dataFromDB = [
    { bloque: 'Articulos', atributo: 'Keywords' },
    { bloque: 'Capacitacion', atributo: 'fecha_aceptacion' },
    { bloque: 'Libros', atributo: 'pais' },
    { bloque: 'Proyectos', atributo: 'paginas' },
    { bloque: 'Libros', atributo: 'volume' }
];

const dataEsquemaJSON = [
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Libros', atributoEntrante: 'paginas' },
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Articulos', atributoEntrante: 'Keywords' },
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Grado Academico', atributoEntrante: 'fecha_aceptacion' },
    { bloqueEntrante: 'Libros', atributoEntrante: 'volume' }
];

const aux = dataEsquemaJSON.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const item = dataFromDB.find(x => x.atributo === curr.atributoEntrante && x.bloque === curr.bloqueEntrante);

  if (!item) prev = [...prev, curr];
  
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(aux)
```

De esta forma, recorres los items de tu arreglo, y mediante la función **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)**, vas sacando los objetos que están en un arreglo y no en el otro.

Nos comentas si tienes dudas.